# Installing Kubuntu made Kodi dominate

Tags: kubuntu, kodi, sddm

About half an hour ago, I did `apt install kubuntu-desktop`, selected `sddm` as my new display manager, and rebooted. The standard, KDE-style login showed, but on logging in I found that Kodi immediately opened in fullscreen mode. I am unable to use anything else (except the `tty` screens), since attempting to exit Kodi (`Power button icon > Exit`) logs me out. Doing `Settings > System Settings > Display > Display mode > Windowed` makes the usable Kodi interface shrink to one part of the screen, but moving the mouse over the rest of the screen just displays an **`×`** as the cursor - there is no desktop environment loaded. What can I do to get back to some usable state? (For example, is there some way to load a desktop environment using a `tty` shell?)

Comment: Does the sudo service lightdm stop makes any significant change?

Comment: If not, you can revert your display manager settings by sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm

Comment: I don't appear to have `kdm` installed, but I have switched back from `sddm` to `lightdm`, which took me back to the familiar Mate desktop. How can I switch to KDE without killing everything again?

Comment: I guess the lightdm is still active and taking the resources of X server. I would make a backup of the installation and then try to purge lightdm and the old mate desktop.

Comment: Was the lightdm service active, when the sddm was on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it by booting into a live instance of Kubuntu.
I had to remove and purge kodi from my hard drive's root directory.
so mount your system partition and

```
sudo chroot /media/ubuntu/<system directory name>
```

Now that your system disk is your root directory you can remove koki

```
sudo apt-get remove koki* -y
sudo apt-get purge kodi* -y
```

That did it for me. After a reboot my system came up normaly.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: thank you - it turned out i was just being really dumb: sddm had set kodi as my default since (out of kodi, mate, plasma) it was first alphabetically; and it not being a dm i had used before i didn't know where the menu to change desktop environment was.